# How do I get my input value to become my eax and equal a given hex value?

Tags: assembly

I have the compiled c file to run this program but it only shows the main. I have dumped the assembly code and need some help getting past the cmp at 8048daf. I have found the amount of leading zeros to get my eax to equal a value but I cant get it to equal 0x338. 
Since it takes my input as a string my understanding is that eax will have either 2, 4, etc numbers as its value because chars are always 2 values as its hex.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000008
```

This is the value I have used as my input to get eax to equal 0x38

```
 08048d7d <phase_5>:
 8048d7d:   55                          push   %ebp
 8048d7e:   89 e5                       mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048d80:   83 ec 48                    sub    $0x48,%esp
 8048d83:   c6 45 f1 00                 movb   $0x0,-0xf(%ebp)
 8048d87:   c6 45 e2 00                 movb   $0x0,-0x1e(%ebp)
 8048d8b:   c6 45 e1 e5                 movb   $0xe5,-0x1f(%ebp)
 8048d8f:   c6 45 e0 e9                 movb   $0xe9,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048d93:   c7 45 ec 38 03 00 00        movl   $0x338,-0x14(%ebp)
 8048d9a:   8b 45 08                    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048d9d:   89 44 24 04                 mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048da1:   8d 45 c8                    lea    -0x38(%ebp),%eax
 8048da4:   89 04 24                    mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048da7:   e8 4c fb ff ff              call   80488f8 <strcpy@plt>
 8048dac:   8b 45 ec                    mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
```

This compare:

```
8048daf:    3d 38 03 00 00              cmp    $0x338,%eax
```

---

```
 8048db4:   74 05                       je     8048dbb <phase_5+0x3e>
 8048db6:   e8 d8 02 00 00              call   8049093 <trigger_bomb>
 8048dbb:   0f b6 45 e0                 movzbl -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 8048dbf:   3c 66                       cmp    $0x66,%al
 8048dc1:   75 10                       jne    8048dd3 <phase_5+0x56>
 8048dc3:   0f b6 45 e1                 movzbl -0x1f(%ebp),%eax
 8048dc7:   3c 69                       cmp    $0x69,%al
 8048dc9:   75 08                       jne    8048dd3 <phase_5+0x56>
 8048dcb:   0f b6 45 e2                 movzbl -0x1e(%ebp),%eax
 8048dcf:   84 c0                       test   %al,%al
 8048dd1:   74 05                       je     8048dd8 <phase_5+0x5b>
 8048dd3:   e8 bb 02 00 00              call   8049093 <trigger_bomb>
 8048dd8:   c9                          leave  
 8048dd9:   c3                          ret
```

Comment: What is your programming problem? It looks like this code has a buffer overflow bug. You should fix it, say, by switching to `strcpy_s` or `strlcpy`, whichever is available to you.

Comment: I think I have to make use of this buffer overlfow to get past this phase. @RaymondChen

Comment: Can you explain how I could make use of this buffer overflow to return to a different spot @RaymondChen

Comment: You should report the vulnerability to the author of the program so they can fix it.

Comment: That would be my teacher. They know its there. @RaymondChen

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to get bytes that don't have printable representation as an input. In your case that are `0x03` and `0x38`. It's easy to get `0x38` since the character `'8'` has that ascii value. But what about `0x3`. Here comes to play `perl` or another interpreted language:

`./a.out $(perl -e 'print "0" x 20 . "\x38\x03"')`

That would get as an input for your program a string consisting of 20 bytes with the characters `'0'` concatenated with two bytes with `0x03 and 0x38` (the `.` is for concatenation).

Another issue is the endianness. Hope you're aware that when we have little endian the bytes in memory are inverted. For example the value `0x12345678` resides in memory as `0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12`. That's why in the input we have `"\x38\x03"` and not `"\x03\x38"`.